# Feedparser cause no attribute error for geo only when looping

Tags: python-2.7, geo, feedparser

I am using feedparser to parse RSS feed from [spotcrime](http://s3.spotcrime.com/cache/rss/sanjose.xml)

However, I am getting "no attribute" error whenever I'm trying to loop through the entries to get the 'geo_long' and 'geo_lat' attribute.

If I don't loop than it works fine:

```
f = feedparser.parse(link)
entries = f.entries
print entries[0].geo_long
```

But when I do it in a loop like this, it starts giving me error

```
for e in entries:
    print e.geo_long
```

And this error is only for geo_long/geo_lat/where attribute on my feed. Other attributes work just fine when accessed in a loop. Can someone please let me know the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to go around this by using e.get('geo_long') instead and it worked. Still don't know why the other way does not work though